# PGSQL duplicate record in same column

Tags: postgresql, duplicates

i have a table and i want to know where duplicate records are present for same columns. These are my columns and i want to get record where group_id or week are different for same code and fweek and newcode

```
Id newcode fweek    code   group_id   week
1  343001 2016-01   343     100        8
2  343002 2016-01   343     100        8
3  343001 2016-01   343     101        08
```

Required record is

```
Id newcode fweek   code group_id  week
3  343001  2016-01 343  101       08
```

Comment: 1) If {group_id , week} were the same, wouldn't it also be a duplicate? 2) is `id` unique ?

Comment: Yes id is unique

Answer (score 0):

To find the duplicate values i have joined the table with itself.
and we need to group the results with code,fweek and newcode to get more than one duplicate rows if they exist. i have used max() to get last inserted row.

you don't need to use is distinct from (it is same for inequality + NULL). if you don't want to compare NULL ones, use <> operator.

You find more information about  here [info](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-comparison.html)

```
select r.*
from your_table r
where r.id in (select max(r.id)
            from your_table r
                 join your_table r2 on r2.code = r.code and r2.fweek = r.fweek and r2.newcode = r.newcode
            where 
            r2.group_id is distinct from r.group_id or 
            r2.week is distinct from r.week
            group by r.code,
                     r.fweek,
                     r.newcode
            having count(*) > 1)
```